# AMPscript Lookup works inside Email Studio - not Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

I'm having some issues with this AMPscript code and getting it to work properly within Journey Builder.

First, here is the code I am working with (I've switched the field names to general names to have it make sense)

```
%%[ VAR @value1, @value2 
SET @value2 = AttributeValue("sending_de_value") 
SET @value1 = Lookup("other_de","other_de_column","other_de_id",@value2) 
]%% 
%%=v(@value1)=%%
```

So, the Journey is using Salesforce Data for the entry source and I tested out the script within Email Studio on the Data Extension that MC creates for the Salesforce Data entry event and the code works as planned. However, in the actual email send through Journey Builder it does not pull in the value.

Has anyone experienced this? The values, etc. all match up.

Comment: Do not see `@entityid` being defined.

Comment: I forgot to switch "entityid" to "value2" when I posted it here. So in my actual code the "value2" is the same as "entityid"

Comment: have you verified that `@value2` is outputting a non-null value in JB?  The issue could be related to the value in the 'Journey Data' is null or does not match what is inside your DE. More info on Journey Data, Attributes/Personalization Strings and Contact Data: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_personalization_in_the_journey_builder_send_email_activity.htm&type=5

Comment: Are you fetching value1 from the DE that gets created for Salesforce data entry source and using that value to lookup value2 from another DE? Or is it visa-versa?

Comment: Is `sending_de_value` a field name in your event source DE used by the Journey and if so, does it contain a value for records injected in the Journey?

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that the issue was with the polling time set up in the MC Connect. Basically, the SF Entry Event was pulling people in faster than the Data we were referencing was coming in. Adding a wait time before the email send resolved this issue.

Thanks everyone for the help!